# Lots of errors when transfering to DARwIN-OP

Tags: linux, compilation, webots

When I try to do cross compilation or remote control with any controller in the last version of webots, whether with some example of the Darwin robot or some controller that I have programmed, I have many errors. I get the following code when I try to remotely control the robot.

```
LinuxCM730.cpp:248: error: prototype for ‘void Robot::LinuxCM730::Sleep(int)’ does not match any in class ‘Robot::LinuxCM730’
../include/LinuxCM730.h:65: error: candidate is: virtual void Robot::LinuxCM730::Sleep(double)
make[1]: *** [LinuxCM730.o] Error 1
make: *** [darwin.a] Error 2
```

```
LinuxCM730.cpp:248: error: prototype for ‘void Robot::LinuxCM730::Sleep(int)’ does not match any in class ‘Robot::LinuxCM730’
../include/LinuxCM730.h:65: error: candidate is: virtual void Robot::LinuxCM730::Sleep(double)
make[2]: *** [LinuxCM730.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/darwin/Linux/lib/darwin.a] Error 2
make: *** [/darwin/Linux/project/webots/transfer/lib/wrapper.a] Error 2
```

```
LinuxCM730.cpp:248: error: prototype for ‘void Robot::LinuxCM730::Sleep(int)’ does not match any in class ‘Robot::LinuxCM730’
../include/LinuxCM730.h:65: error: candidate is: virtual void Robot::LinuxCM730::Sleep(double)
make[1]: *** [LinuxCM730.o] Error 1
make: *** [/darwin/Linux/lib/darwin.a] Error 2
```

```
/darwin/Linux/build/LinuxMotionTimer.cpp:15: error: ‘Robot::MotionManager* Robot::LinuxMotionTimer::m_Manager’ is not a static member of ‘class Robot::LinuxMotionTimer’
/darwin/Linux/build/LinuxMotionTimer.cpp:16: error: ‘bool Robot::LinuxMotionTimer::m_TimerRunning’ is not a static member of ‘class Robot::LinuxMotionTimer’
/darwin/Linux/build/LinuxMotionTimer.cpp:17: error: ‘void* Robot::LinuxMotionTimer::m_TimerID’ is not a static member of ‘class Robot::LinuxMotionTimer’
/darwin/Linux/build/LinuxMotionTimer.cpp:20: error: prototype for ‘void Robot::LinuxMotionTimer::TimerProc(int)’ does not match any in class ‘Robot::LinuxMotionTimer’
/darwin/Linux/include/LinuxMotionTimer.h:27: error: candidate is: static void* Robot::LinuxMotionTimer::TimerProc(void*)
/darwin/Linux/build/LinuxMotionTimer.cpp:26: error: no ‘void Robot::LinuxMotionTimer::Initialize(Robot::MotionManager*)’ member function declared in class ‘Robot::LinuxMotionTimer’
make: *** [LinuxMotionTimer.o] Error 1
```

```
sudo: /darwin/Linux/project/webots/remote_control/remote_control: command not found
```

Comment: Which version of the robot are you using? Have you tried to press the uninstall button (just to the right to the one you pressed) and the re-start remote-control again?

Comment: I am using the darwin robot op 1 (the first version) and yes, already press the uninstall button

Comment: Ok, do you know which version of the darwin-op framework is installed on your robot? You can see this in the 'ReleaseNote.txt ' file.

Comment: DARwIn-OP v1.4.0 . Also when i tried to run some demos directly on the robot the same messages appear on the console

Comment: In that case you should probably try to update to the latest one (v1.6.1): https://sourceforge.net/p/darwinop/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/darwin/

Comment: I have updated the framework and errors continue to happen, should I do something else? I could not via svn, instead download the files

Comment: Once updated, did you remove Webots from the robot (with the uninstall button of the robot-window) and re-tried to transfer a controller?

Comment: yes, I removed it and it doesn't work